# re hyperledger's node/sdk: there is no typing definition( index.d.ts )

Tags: hyperledger

While the hlc is written in typescript; I could not find the typings definition, index.d.ts

Does it really exist?

Or is there plan to create one?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in that the typings directory isn't published to npm.  Am looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this needs to be fixed. We will address shortly and I will post a link to the pull request here for you to track. Please stay tuned.

Comment: Please track the pull request to address this issue here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/pull/2279

Comment: This return 404.